# errors building a Blend solution

Tags: wpf, silverlight, expression-blend, blend

I downloaded an MS tutorial file that was Blend 3 and updated it to 4; getting errors like the one below. It seems to have something to do with language resources that I don't care about, and don't see how to remove. Other Blend 4 projects work fine.

Can anyone suggest a fix?

Cheers

```
    c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(3001,9): error MSB3021:  
Unable to copy file "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\Silverlight\v4.0\Prototyping\Libraries
\de\Microsoft.Expression.Prototyping.Runtime.resources.dll" 
to "..\Bin\Debug\de\Microsoft.Expression.Prototyping.Runtime.resources.dll". 

The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, 
and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get these kind of issues when I extract files(Sample Proj) to Desktop or My Documents Folder. I would suggest move your whole project folder to C:\ and run. That usually fixes my issues related to that error